# VTK - how to flip\mirror image

Tags: c++, vtk

I'm using `vtkResliceImageViewer` to display image (multi-planar reconstruction). How can I flip\mirror that image vertically and horizontally? Operating with camera is not working as expected, since flip has to take into consideration also camera rotation angle, so it gets very complicated. It would be great if there is a way to change image's texture coordinates. Is this possible?

Comment: What about applying vtkImageFlip?

Comment: I tried, but couldn't find any example how to use it with vtkResliceImageViewer.

Answer (score 1):

```
 // Create an image
 vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageMandelbrotSource> source =
 vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageMandelbrotSource>::New();
 source->Update();
 // Flip the image
 vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageFlip> flipYFilter =
 vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageFlip>::New();
 flipYFilter->SetFilteredAxis(1); // flip y axis
 flipYFilter->SetInputConnection(source->GetOutputPort());
 flipYFilter->Update();
 // Create the Viewer
 vtkSmartPointer<vtkResliceImageViewer> viewer =
 vtkSmartPointer<vtkResliceImageViewer>::New();
 viewer->SetInputData(flipYFilter->GetOutput())
```